# Solve the following Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am not sure what to do with this;

$-\csc^2x + (\sqrt 2)\csc x \cot x = 0  \text{ between} (0, \pi)$

Do I convert to sine and cosine and then add the identities together?

Answer (score 1):

Given $$-\csc^2 x+\sqrt{2}\cdot \csc x\cot x = 0\Rightarrow \csc^2 x-\sqrt{2}\cdot \csc x\cot x = 0$$

So $$\csc x\cdot \left[\csc x-\sqrt{2}\cot x\right] = 0$$

So we get either $$\displaystyle \csc x= 0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sin x} =0$$ or $$\displaystyle \csc x-\sqrt{2}\cot x=0\Rightarrow \frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos x}{\sin x} = 0$$

Now Here $x\in \left(0,\pi\right)\;,$ We get $\displaystyle \csc x= \frac{1}{\sin x}>0$

So only real solution exists when $$\displaystyle \csc x-\sqrt{2}\cot x=0\Rightarrow \frac{1-\sqrt{2}\cos x}{\sin x} = 0$$

so we Get $$\displaystyle 1-\sqrt{2}\sin x = 0\Rightarrow \sin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sin \left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$.

So we get Real solutions are $$\displaystyle x = \frac{\pi}{4}\;\;,\frac{3\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: I am not seeing how you replaced cos x with sin x and removed the denominator, could you elaborate? Thanks